# Conditional Python regex and named group

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
/foo/bar
```

and the following regex:

```
/(?P<g1>.*)/(?P<g2>.*)$
```

The string is matched by the pattern and two groups are captured:

g1 = foo

g2 = bar

How can I force an optional match?

I need that "/bar" is captured to g1 = "bar"
(but not /bar/) if there is no second group the could be matched?

(Testing it with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bT1eP0/1))

Thanks

Comment: unclear, could you explain a bit.

Comment: 1. "/foo" goes to group g1.

2. "/foo/" no match.

3. "foo/bar" matches g1 = foo, g2 = bar.

Comment: Well, this is difficult to understand, let me guess... How about [`/(?P<g1>[^/]*)/?(?P<g2>[^/]*)?(?<!/)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bT1eP0/2)?

Comment: Yes it works as expected for /foo/bar and /foo.
The problem is if I have:
/foo/bar/foo2/bar2. This matches the foo2 and bar2, I had expected no match

Comment: Add a start of string anchor then: [`^/(?P<g1>[^/]*)/?(?P<g2>[^/]*)?(?<!/)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bT1eP0/6). Or for demo, with `\n`: [`^/(?P<g1>[^/\n]*)/?(?P<g2>[^/\n]*)?(?<!/)$`](https://regex101.com/r/bT1eP0/7).

Comment: @user2624744: I posted my solution, please check. Also, added the regex explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a start of string anchor `^` to restrict the string to only have 2 slahses. And as Avinash Raj noted you need to make some parts of your regex optional.

```
^/(?P<g1>[^/\n]*)/?(?P<g2>[^/\n]*)?(?<!/)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT1eP0/7)

The `\n` is only necessary in multiline mode so that `[^/]` could not match a newline.

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^/` - Start of string and literal `/`
- `(?P<g1>[^/\n]*)` - The first capturing group that is obligatory (must match 1 time) that matches any character but `/` (or `\n` too if you keep it), 0 or more times
- `/?` - 0 or 1 `/` character
- `(?P<g2>[^/\n]*)?` - Optional second capture group matching 0 or more characters other than `/` and `\n`
- `(?<!/)$` - End of string that is preceded with a character other than `/`.

Comment: This regex is almost perfect, but would it be possible to restrict the group by passing additional conditions. Assume I need to match
g1 where only three letters are allowed?

so that:
/foo and
/foo/barbar matches.

but 
/fooo and /fooo/bar don't.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for [`^/(?P<g1>[^/\n]{3}(?=(?:/[^/\n]+)?$))(?:/(?P<g2>[^/\n]+)?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/bT1eP0/8).

Comment: The problem now is that it matches also /foo/

Comment: It should not, look again at my fiddle a comment above. ``\foo\`` is not highlighted.